# How to replace some substrings with consequitve numbers in a string using regular expression in java?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text:

```
some cool color #12eedd more cool colors #4567aa
```

I want that this string will be transformed to:

```
some cool color #{1} more cool colors #{2}
```

How is it possible to do it in Java (1.6)?

What I've found so far is the regex for color: `#[0-9abcdef]{3,6}`

Comment: I've found the regex for color: `#[0-9abcdef]{3,6}` But I don't know how I can iterate over string and replace the colors.

Comment: Why not `[0-9a-f]` instead of `[0-9abcdef]`...

Comment: @crush because it makes me more fun to write it that way :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `appendReplacement` and `appendTail` from Matcher class

```
String data = "some cool color #12eedd more cool colors #4567aa";
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#[0-9a-f]{3,6}", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
int i = 1;
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "#{" + i++ + "}");
}
m.appendTail(sb);//in case there is some text left after last match

String replaced = sb.toString();
System.out.println(replaced);
```

output:

```
some cool color #{1} more cool colors #{2}
```

Comment: This is the correct/ best answer, because it enables __capture__ of the color values. These can then be stored for substitution, wherever the poster intends to put them. (This question is obviously about substitution.)

Comment: @ThomasW Not to mention, it iterates over the string a single time.

Comment: Should probably flag the pattern as case-insensitive, or add `A-F` to the pattern.

Comment: +1 for learning me something new with the `appendReplacement` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try without regex as this

```
    String str="some cool color #12eedd more cool colors #4567aa";
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    String[] arr=str.split(" ");
    int count=1;
    for(String i:arr){
       if(i.charAt(0)=='#'){
           sb.append("#{"+count+"} ");
           count++;
       }
        else {
           sb.append(i+" ");
       }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

out put:

```
 some cool color #{1} more cool colors #{2}
```

Comment: What if there is a `#` in the string that isn't followed by a hexadecimal number?

Comment: Seconded. I wouldn't consider this reliable to **capture** the color values, since the matching is too weak. This problem is essentially about **substituting** values & capturing the data -- reliably -- is an essential part of that. Discarding the color values (or not capturing them accurately) is unjustifiable information-loss -- this is rubbish code not a professional-quality solution.

Comment: I know it sounds harsh, but information-loss without a good reason is a big no-no.

Comment: it could be strengthen by actually matching the word `i` against the color regex pattern

Answer (score 0):

Well may be this is not you are looking for but you have other option without using regex, this is simple with little bit complexion :)

```
StringBuilder q = new StringBuilder("some cool color #12eedd more cool colors #4567aa");
int i;
int j=1;
while(q.indexOf("#")>0){
    q.replace(i=q.indexOf("#"),i+7, "${"+ j++ +"}");
}
String result = q.toString().replaceAll("\\$", "#");
System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
some cool color #{1} more cool colors #{2}
```

Comment: Thank you! But the sign '#' must not stand always for color. The color should match the pattern.